# What verb do I use when 'y(ies)' is used together in a sentence

Tags: verbs

For example, should it state: The beneficiary(ies) on your account **were** updated? OR The beneficiary(ies) on your account **was** updated? I'm thinking the first, but want to be sure.

Comment: You should not write with parenned plurals at all. It's too shorthandy confusing.

Comment: Understood, but there is a possibility that one beneficiary is added or more than one are added so I wanted to be able to cover both possibilities.

Comment: I confess I had to Google tchrist's "parenned" - and got nowhere - and still in all seriousness, why would you think about trusting any service provider who tried to distort the language that way?

Taking the trouble to count the “beneficiaries” on your account would always yield either the correct number - if accounts had “beneficiaries”.

Avoiding the problem would always either force the SP to use “beneficiaries” or reveal the SP’s incompetence.

Comment: If you use an ambiguous-number subject indicated by a slash, use an ambiguous-number verb to agree with it, like _was/were_